# How to combine multiple excel files having multiple equal number of sheets in each excel files

Tags: python, pandas

I am able to combine multiple excel files having one sheet currently.
***I want to combine multiple sheets having two different sheets in each excel file with giving name to each sheets*** How can I achieve this?

Here below is my current code for combining single sheet in multiple excel files without giving sheet name to Combined excel file

```
import pandas as pd

# filenames
excel_names = ["xlsx1.xlsx", "xlsx2.xlsx", "xlsx3.xlsx"]

# read them in
excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in excel_names]

# turn them into dataframes
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels]

    # delete the first row for all frames except the first
    # i.e. remove the header row -- assumes it's the first
    frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]

    # concatenate them..
    combined = pd.concat(frames)

    # write it out
    combined.to_excel("c.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First combine the first and the second sheet separately

```
import pandas as pd

# filenames
excel_names = ["xlsx1.xlsx", "xlsx2.xlsx", "xlsx3.xlsx"]

def combine_excel_to_dfs(excel_names, sheet_name):
    sheet_frames = [pd.read_excel(x, sheet_name=sheet_name) for x in excel_names]
    combined_df = pd.concat(sheet_frames).reset_index(drop=True)

    return combined_df

df_first = combine_excel_to_dfs(excel_names, 0)
df_second = combine_excel_to_dfs(excel_names, 1)
```

### Use pd.ExcelWriter

And write these sheets to the same excel file:

```
# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('two_sheets_combined.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
df_first.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
df_second.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: In sheet_frames = [pd.read_excel(x, sheetname=sheetname) for x in excel_names] line, sheetname should be sheet_name.. It worked for me.. Thank you..:)

Comment: how do we convert the same to csv?

Comment: I see, `sheetname` has been deprecated since pandas 0.21, should use `sheet_name` now. Going to edit the answer. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
#number of sheets
N = 2
#get all sheets to nested lists
frames = [[x.parse(y, index_col=None) for y in x.sheet_names] for x in excels]
#print (frames)

#combine firt dataframe from first list with first df with second list...
combined = [pd.concat([x[i] for x in frames], ignore_index=True) for i in range(N)]
#print (combined)

#write to file
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('c.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for i, x in enumerate(combined):
    x.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet{}'.format(i + 1))
writer.save()
```

Comment: It is combining both the sheets but in second sheet it is giving lot of gap between one file data to another

Comment: I guess there is still something wrong with x.sheet_names

Comment: I test it in pandas 0.22.0 and it working nice. What is error?

Comment: Yeah, It is working... Sorry for the inconvenience.. By the way how to check the pandas version?

Comment: print (pd.show_versions()) is nice, because all versions.