# Merge the multiple Excel sheet into one Excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have one folder in this I have 3 excel files, M,N, P and in the M, N,P three sheets one_, two_ and three_

```
Main
|
|_M.xlsx 
|       |_ one_M.xlsx
|       |_ two_M.xlsx
|       |_ three_M.xlsx
|       |_f_M.xlsx
|       |_O.M.xlsx
|_N.xlsx 
|       |_ one_N.xlsx
|       |_ two_N.xlsx
|       |_ three_N.xlsx
|       |_f_M.xlsx
|       |_O.M.xlsx
|_P.xlsx 
        |_ one_P.xlsx
        |_ two_P.xlsx
        |_ three_P.xlsx
        |_f_M.xlsx
        |_O.M.xlsx
```

and I want the One excel file after merge like this

```
Main
|
|_Main.xlsx 
       |_ one_M.xlsx
       |_ two_M.xlsx
       |_ three_M.xlsx
       |_ one_N.xlsx
       |_ two_N.xlsx
       |_ three_N.xlsx
       |_ one_P.xlsx
       |_ two_P.xlsx
       |_ three_P.xlsx'
```

How can I do this using pandas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine multiple excel files having multiple equal number of sheets in each excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48780464/how-to-combine-multiple-excel-files-having-multiple-equal-number-of-sheets-in-ea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use `sheet_name=None` in `pd.read_excel`, you can read in all the sheets in the workbook at one time. They will be merged in an Ordered Dictionary with dataframes. Keys will be as sheets' names.

Try this code:

```
 df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(workbook_path, sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)
```

If you want only to merge sheets in one file:

```
 paths_list=['path1', 'path2',...]
 with pd.ExcelWriter('output_file_path.xlsx') as wr:
          For path in paths_list:
                 df=pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name =None)
                 [df[sheetName].to_excel(wr, sheet_name=sheetName) for sheetName in df]
```

Comment: I update the question, if I required only specific sheet then what can I do?

Comment: Indicate it in `sheet_name='sheet_name' `